# twitter-bootstrap-rails 4.0.0 with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-rails

https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails says:
Twitter Bootstrap for Rails 5 and **Rails 4** Asset Pipeline

but after bundle install I see this:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.1.7) was resolved to 4.1.7, which depends on
      actionpack (= 4.1.7)

    twitter-bootstrap-rails (~> 4.0.0) was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 5.0.1, ~> 5.0)
```

Is it possible to make twitter-bootstrap-rails 4.0.0 worked with Rails 4.1.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Cloned twitter-bootstrap-rails repo
- Analyzed latest commits
- Changed gemspecs
- ????
- PROFIT!!!

Answer (score 1):

Version you are using for `twitter-bootstrap-rails` is `4.0.0` having dependency on rails `>= 5.0.1, ~> 5.0` you can check [here](https://rubygems.org/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails/versions/4.0.0).

Use version `3.2.0` instead, it will work for you.

```
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails", '~> 3.2.0'
```

Comment: > Version you are using for twitter-bootstrap-rails is 4.0.0 having dependency on rails >= 5.0.1, ~> 5.0 you can check here.

Yes, I saw it already.
But... It's legacy application and it's builded with 4.0.0 version of twitter-bootstrap-rails gem. Maybe dependecies were different some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

I vote for using bootstrap 4 **WITHOUT** gem.

In some cases and my experiences, this kind of implementation need less work when we integrate it to Rails manually :

- download all the needed CSS, Java, creatives
- put them all in the proper Rails assets folder
- include them properly on the assets main file ( application.js, application.css, images )
- use it by following the proper guide from the bootstrap website
- have a desired looks as you wish

This way, you won't have to worries about gem dependencies or even ruby and rails versions.

And totally welcoming any better ideas than mine.

Comment: Interesting.Is this good manual: https://dev.mikamai.com/2013/12/09/integrate-bootstrap-3-without-gem/ for implementing?

Comment: @AlexJhonson, I will try to summarise what I did later. But for now, this article looks promising : https://gist.github.com/iamatypeofwalrus/6400118. Happy trying